# Как в Jenkins получить процент покрытия junit тестами?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit, jenkins

Есть java проект с junit тестами.
Проект подключен к Jenkins.
В Jenkins выполняются тесты. часть кода из Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('test') {
        app.withRun('') {
            c ->
                parallel 'junit test': {
                    app.inside {
                        sh 'mvn test'
                        junit '**/surefire-reports/**/*.xml'
                    }
                }, 'integration test': {
                    app.inside {
                        sh 'mvn -P=systest test'
                        junit '**/surefire-reports/**/*.xml'
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Но также необходимо получить процент покрытия кода тестами. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавит в проект `jacoco-maven-plagin` и эти строчки в jenkins-pipeline

```
stage('Test') {
    sh "mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugins:prepare-agent package"
    // Публикуем отчет о покрытии кода в Jenkins 
    jacoco()
}
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, в самом jenkins дополнительно нужно устанавливать плагин ?

Comment: получаю No such DSL method 'jacoco' found among steps [archive, bat, build,

Comment: Да, надо в jenkins установить этот плагин

Comment: Может подскажете еще, как в это покрытие добавить интеграционные тесты?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885772/jacoco-simple-integration-test-solution

Answer (score 1):

Добавить плагин для покрытия в maven, что-то типа:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <!-- Code Coverage report generation -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-code-coverage-report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Добавить/настроить плагин в Jenkins:[JaCoCo Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JaCoCo+Plugin)

Это один из вариантов, на самом деле вариантов много